# How to remove/disable Add to Cart function in OpenCart

Tags: php, module, content-management-system, opencart

How do I disable or remove add to cart, and checkout functions on OpenCart?

I have a website, and it's like a store catalog. I mean, it is not an online store, so I don't need these functions and would like to disable it, so people can see the price, but they can't buy it online.

Comment: This is not a programming question and should be asked on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know, OpenCart is E-commerce software which is meant to sell product online, so there is no feature of removing add to cart.

If you want you can do it in a custom way by disabling the `addToCart()` operation:

```
catalog>view>javascript>common::addToCart() comment the operational part
system>library>cart::add() comment the operational part
```

This will help to disable the function of `addToCart()`.

To remove add to cart button, add script to `footer.tpl` before `</body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.cart, #cart').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: Worked on Opencart 1.5.4